# Android cant set notification

Tags: java, android

I am trying to understand how the notification from an app is working, this is my code that i did from a tutorial but when i run the app i see no notification,if this is not the right way and someone could upload an example i would be very grateful.

````
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        //Views

        Button mBtnNotify;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBtnNotify = findViewById(R.id.btnNotification);

        mBtnNotify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                pushNotification("This is the title","this is the text");

            }
        });

    }

    public void pushNotification(String title, String body){

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);


    }

}```
````

Comment: android studio is where you write your android code. i don't think you're asking about the IDE here, so i've updated your title, you're welcome to change it back if you disagree :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on API 26+ you have to create a notification channel to show notifications

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Answer (score 0):

There are a lots of tips to give you.

1. AlarmManager requires a channel since API 26
2. You "Battery Safe" algorithm could not afford you to push notification. So you need to let your app push them giving it the permission, do it from Settings->battery. (steps change phone by phone). This problem is dued to manifacturer (chinese as HUAWEI, OPPO ecc..)

I am gonna post a my project:
[project](https://github.com/Gabriele-P03/Note)

Edit: p.s. if you take a look at my project, select 1.0.1 branch

NotificationWorker:

```
public class NotificationWorker extends Worker {

private Context context;
private WorkerParameters workerParameters;

public NotificationWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
    this.context = context;
    this.workerParameters = workerParams;
}

/**
 * Method called when the trigger delay is passed.
 * Notification is pushed and shows own info
 */
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "noteChannel")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo)

            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200})

            .setContentTitle(workerParameters.getInputData().getString("title"))
            .setContentInfo(workerParameters.getInputData().getString("date") +
                    " at " + workerParameters.getInputData().getString("time"))
            .setContentText(workerParameters.getInputData().getString("description"))
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);



    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

    notificationManagerCompat.notify(283, builder.build());

    return Result.success();
}

/**
 * Since Android O (API 26), a channel for notifications
 * must be set to the Notification Manager
 *
 * For more details see its doc
 * @see NotificationChannel
 *
 * This method is called by MainActivity#onCreate()
 */
public static void createNotificationChannel(Context context){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        CharSequence name = "NoteChannel";
        String description = "Channel for Note notification";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("note", name, importance);

        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        channel.enableVibration(true);

        channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{400, 100, 400, 100, 200, 100, 200});
        channel.setDescription(description);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}

/**
 * Schedule the new notification delayed as the difference
 * between the current date in millis and the notification's
 * @see Nota#getDelay()
 *
 * Passes to the constructor of NotficationWorker, called by builder,
 * date, time, title and description about @nota
 *
 * @param nota
 */
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static void setNewNotification(Nota nota, Context context){

    WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context);

    OneTimeWorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker.class)
            .setInitialDelay(nota.getDelay(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .addTag(nota.getDate() + "@" + nota.getTime() + ".txt")
            .setInputData(new Data.Builder()
                    .putString("date", nota.getDate())
                    .putString("time", nota.getTime())
                    .putString("title", nota.getTitle())
                    .putString("description", nota.getNote()).build())
            .build();

    workManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Hope to have helped you :-)